# db2 sql script file

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I have an oracle script that I am trying to convert to valid db2 syntax.  Within this sql file I have various calls to other sql files passing in a parameter using the '@' syntax.

e.g.

```
@script1 param1
@script2 param2
```

Can anyone help me with valid db2 equivalent statements?  Is there an equivalent run command in db2? is it possible to pass parameters to a sql script in db2?

thanks,

smauel

Answer (score 12):

The thing you are after is the [DB2 Command Line Processor (CLP).](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0010412.htm)

If you want to execute a script, you would execute in the CLP:

```
db2 -vtf script1
```

-f tells the CLP to run command input from the given file.

Here's the [full list of options](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0010410.htm).

Unfortunately db2 doesn't support passing parameters to a script.  You would have to combine your db2 -vtf commands with other scripting commands (such as sed) to generate the scripts for you, as in [this example](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1501961&page=8).

Answer (score 5):

1) place the *filename.sql* file in SQLLIB/BIN

2) run db2cmd

3) execute this to connect to the required db

```
 db2 connect to *dbname* user *userid* using *password*
```

4) excute this command

```
 db2 -vtf *filename.sql*
```

This should execute the sql statements in the file one by one. The sql statements must be ending with a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way for passing in parameters, that works fine for us (it might not work with (complex) multiline sql statements).

Convert your sql-script into a shell script by adding 'db2 ' at the beginning of each line. Than you can use the standard variable replacement syntax from your shell in your scripts.

so instead of

```
insert ...
update ...
```

you will have

```
db2 insert ...
db2 update ...
```

Answer (score 0):

---

1. Place file in one directory.
2. Open db2cmd.exe as administrator
3. Navigate to directory where you have place the script
4. type db2 -vtf `